# VBA do while loop not calculating in UDF

Tags: vba, loops, user-defined-functions, do-while

I'm getting a value error when trying to simply have one range of values, input as doubles, for instance: a = 0.7, b = 0.9, c = 0.8, d = 0.8, e = 1.
The function needs to reduce the reference values (f-j) by 0.05 until the sum of these (positive values only) is equal to or less than 0.1.
Getting Value error so I'm not sure what where it's going wrong. Please help!

```
Function AClass(a, b, c, d, e, Optional crit As Variant = "TRUE") As Variant

f = 0.8
g = 1
h = 1
i = 1
j = 0.9

api = Application.MRound(((a + b + c + d + e) / 5), 0.05) 'check to compare whether average of api or sumref is higher
sumref = Application.MRound(((f + g + h + i + j) / 5), 0.05)

Udeviation1 = Application.If((f - a) > 0, f - a, 0)
Udeviation2 = Application.If((g - b) > 0, g - b, 0)
Udeviation3 = Application.If((h - c) > 0, h - c, 0)
Udeviation4 = Application.If((i - d) > 0, i - d, 0)
Udeviation5 = Application.If((j - e) > 0, j - e, 0)
Udevsum = Udeviation1 + Udeviation2 + Udeviation3 + Udeviation4 + Udeviation5 'setting the range for the ifsum below


If api < sumref Then
    Do While Udevsum <= 0.1 'whilst sum of positive unfavorable deviations are greater than 0.1, proceed to add 0.05 to each term (f-j)
        f = f - 0.05
        g = g - 0.05
        h = h - 0.05
        i = i - 0.05
        j = j - 0.05
        Udeviation1 = Application.If((f - a) > 0, f - a, 0)
        Udeviation2 = Application.If((g - b) > 0, g - b, 0)
        Udeviation3 = Application.If((h - c) > 0, h - c, 0)
        Udeviation4 = Application.If((i - d) > 0, i - d, 0)
        Udeviation5 = Application.If((j - e) > 0, j - e, 0)
        Udevsum = Udeviation1 + Udeviation2 + Udeviation3 + Udeviation4 + Udeviation5 'recalculate unfavorable deviations
    Loop

End If

AClass = g

End Function
```

Edit: Thank you all for helping. The combination of Application.If changed to Iff and changing Do While to Do Until has solved it!

Comment: `application.if` isn't a thing as far as I can tell, just use a normal `If` statement.

Comment: `Application.If` should be `IIf()`